# Find item in array of arrays

Tags: node.js

I have a scenario where I wish to find an item within an array of arrays and then if contained delete the item.

```
a = [ [ 'Brian', 80 ],
  [ 'Sue', 72 ],
  [ 'Mary', 18 ],
  [ 'Harry', 60 ],
  [ 'Brian', 40 ] ];
```

I had originally thought of using indexOf to find the item and then splice to remove it however cannot use indexOf as I only know the value of element[0] and not element[1], for example I know "Harry" but not his age:

```
index = a.indexOf(["Harry", ?])
a.splice(index, 1);
```

The other scenario I have it to update the value and create it if it does not exist.

**Edit**
New to aync programming however just realised that in an async env that the array elements may be changed as the array is being processed so index item number X may no longer be x when I delete the item one or two commands later...

Comment: For removing: `a = a.filter(x => x.indexOf('Harry') == -1)`

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you want to return a new array or modify the original one.

If you want to return a **new** one without the matching element you can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var newone = a.filter(function(val) { return val[0] !== 'Harry'; });
```

To add new elements and return a **new** array you can also use [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

While, if you want to delete/insert/replace the element in the **original** array, the correct way is using [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) or the faster [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for add new items to the end:

```
// Reverse order because the array is re-indexed on splice
for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  if (a[i] === 'Harry') a.splice(i, 1);
```

Btw, consider use helper libraries like [`lodash`](http://lodash.com) or [`underscorejs`](http://underscorejs.org/) for manipulate array in a safe way.

Comment: Shouldn't `val.indexOf('Harry') === -1;` be `val[0] !== 'Harry';`? The age slot probably wont contain the name.

Comment: If you want to look only into the first slot yes, use `val[0] === ...`. Remember that the filter condition should return true to keep / false to remove.

Comment: Exactly. You want to keep all entries that are *not* Harry (thus `val[0] !== 'Harry';` is true if it is *not* Harry, see: https://jsfiddle.net/r37jc4rt/). Checking all slots when only the first one is relevant looks like a potential source for bugs.

Comment: Yes of course, it depends of your use case. I just changed the examples.

Answer (score -2):

you can slice an item from list

```
    a.forEach(function(x){
        if((x.indexOf("Brian")) === 0) a.splice([a.indexOf(x)],1)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you however I know the name but not the age... so when finding the item I have to search on same only.

Comment: sorry you have the correction now. i thought you can change "Brain" to your desired value or change it to a variable